# Does a first integral exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following exercise:

*Consider in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the system $\dot{x} = f(x)$ with divergence $\nabla . f(x) = 0$. So the phase-flow is volume preserving. Does this mean that a first integral exists?*

The definition that I have of a first integral is as follows:

*Consider the equation $\dot{x} = f(x), x\in D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$; the function $F(x)$ is called first integral of the equation if in $D$ holds*
$$
L_tF = 0
$$
*with respect to the vector function $x(t)$.*

Here $L_t$ is the orbital derivative so that $L_tF = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\dot{x} = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}\dot{x_1} + \ldots + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_n}\dot{x_n}$.

The function $f(x)$ looks something like this:

$$
f = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1\\
f_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We have $\nabla . f(x) = 0$ which means that $\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} + \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} = 0$ but I don't know how I should use this to determine whether a first integral exists.

**Question:** How do I determine whether a first integral exists?

Comment: Consider a first order equation $f_2 \,dx_1 - f_1 \,dx_2 = 0 $. It is an exact equation whose integral curves coincide with integral curves of your first order system of equations. This first order equation is exact. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately I can't really.. How do you know that the integral curves from the first order equation $f_2d_{x_1} - f_1d_{x_2} = 0$ coincide with integral curves of my first order system of equations?

Comment: It is a common trick to reduce system $$\dot{x}_1 = f_1, \; \dot{x}_2 = f_2$$ to the first order equation $\frac{dx_1}{dx_2} = \frac{f_1}{f_2}$ or $\frac{dx_2}{dx_1} = \frac{f_2}{f_1}$ (this can be done using inverse function theorem). Then you can just prove something like: 1) if $x_2 = g(x_1)$ is a solution curve of a first-order equation, then vector field $\lbrace f_1 (x_1, x_2), f_2 (x_1, x_2) \rbrace$ is tangent to it; 2) if $(\gamma(t), \delta(t))$ is a solution curve of a system, its own slope field coincides with a slope field from first order equation.